# Are these 2 lines of code the same ? JS vs Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In ruby:

```
->  { 10.times {|i| puts i} }.call
```

Javascript:

```
(function (){
    for (i = 0; i<10; i++){
        console.log(i);
    }
})()
```

Im coming from a JS background and something peaked my interest when learning about lambdas and Procs where it says that those are function without names which are called. That reminded me of the anonymous functions or IIFE in javascript.

Are these 2 examples the same? if not what is the difference ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `for(var i = 0;...)`. Even IIFE can't protect you from this.

Comment: Also, "IIFE" and "anonymous function" are not synonyms

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, sure, however when running in node it will create  global variable i and iterate it (which doesn't matter in this question) just curious on are those 2 things the same.. or am I missing something.

Comment: The ruby version doesn't pollute the global state.

Comment: They are the same in their output, but *wildly* different in their implementation. IIFEs are not useful in Ruby, and there is no reason to wrap arbitrary code in a lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines are very different in almost every aspect.

The closest ECMAScript equivalent to this Ruby snippet:

```ruby
-> { 10.times {|i| puts i} }.call
```

would be something like this:

```js
(() => { 10.times(i => puts(i)) }).call()
```

Unfortunately, numbers can't have methods in ECMAScript, so we will have to resort to something like this:

```js
(() => { times(10, i => puts(i)) }).call()
```

Obviously, in order for this to work, we need to add some Ruby library support code:

```js
(() => { times(10, i => puts(i)) }).call()

function times(i, f) { if (i-- === 0) return; else { times(i, f); f(i) }}
function puts(s) { console.log(s) }
```

That's still not very much alike the original Ruby semantics, but much closer than your proposal:

- Your proposal leaks `i` into the global scope, the Ruby code doesn't even leak `i` at all, it is local to the innermost block.
- There is no function call operator in Ruby, instead you use the method `Proc#call`, which ECMAScript also has (`Function.prototype.call`).
- You use a `for` loop, whereas the Ruby code uses a method on `Integer` for iteration.
- `Kernel#puts` will write implicitly to whatever you have defined as the default output stream, whereas your proposed ECMAScript solution will explicitly always write to the console.
- `self` is lexically bound in Ruby, but `this` is dynamically bound to the function object itself in ECMAScript, unless you use an arrow function literal, which binds `this` lexixally.

On the other hand, the closest Ruby equivalent to this:

```js
(function (){
    for (i = 0; i<10; i++){
        console.log(i);
    }
})()
```

Would be something like this:

```ruby
-> { $i = 0; while $i < 10 do $stdout.puts($i); $i += 1 end }.()
```

Again, this is not 100% equivalent:

- Ruby doesn't have a `for` loop (only a `for … in` iterator), so the closest thing is a `while` loop.
- Ruby doesn't have a call operator, `.()` is just syntactic sugar for the `call` method.
- `this` in a nested function expression is dynamically bound, `self` in Ruby is lexical.